# Elastic(search): Query result date format differs from stored format

Tags: date, format, elasticsearch

got a problem with the elastic date format conversion when I parse the results from a query. So i have a default mapping on a date field as following:

```
"timestamp" : {
  "type" : "date",
  "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
}
```

and it is stored as `"timestamp":"2015-05-06T08:52:56.387Z"`
if I execute a max aggregation on that field I get a long value:

```
"timestamp_max": {
  "value": 1430902071110
}
```

however I want the value be the same as it is stored. I read that one can specify the format in the aggregation but its not working. I tried:

```
"aggregations":{
  "timestamp_max":{
    "max":{
      "field":"timestamp",
      "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
    }
  }
}
```

but this gives a SearchParseException `... SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.05.07][0]: query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+no_cache(timestamp:[1429357190515 TO 1431949190515])))],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Unexpected token VALUE_STRING in [timestamp_max].]]; ...`

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards,
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to specify the date format using the [correct formatting pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html#date-format-pattern) like this:

```
"aggregations":{
  "timestamp_max":{
    "max":{
      "field":"timestamp",
      "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that this is only working from ES 1.5.0 onwards. See the [related issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6812) on the ES github.

Comment: oh didn't notice it was from 1.5 onwards... thanks for the hint :)

Comment: For clarification: my aggregation with `"format" : "dateOptionalTime"` works fine, I just used wrong version.

Comment: Also, the formatted value will show up in the `value_as_string` field